# Select singers whose spouse is/was also singer using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, dbpedia

I have tried the following query at [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) but it is not working.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/><br/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/><br/>

    SELECT Distinct (?singer),?wife 
    WHERE { 
            ?x dbo:musicalArtist ?singer.
            ?singer dbo:spouse ?wife.
            FILTER(?wife a dbo:MusicalArtist)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not a legal SPARQL query. The most obvious way would be to simply use another join:

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?singer ?wife 
WHERE { 
 ?x dbo:musicalArtist ?singer.
 ?singer dbo:spouse ?wife.
 ?wife a dbo:MusicalArtist
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a FILTER for the existence of triple pattern by writing:

`FILTER EXISTS {?wife a dbo:MusicalArtist}`

Comment: Ok. If this answers your question, don't forget to "accept" it. This will mark this question as completed

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query seek re., musicians whose spouses aren't (or weren't) also musicians.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

    SELECT DISTINCT ?musicArtist ?musicArtistSpouse 
    WHERE { 
            ?x dbo:musicalArtist ?musicArtist.
            ?musicArtist dbo:spouse ?musicArtistSpouse.
            FILTER(! EXISTS {?musicArtistSpouse a dbo:MusicalArtist} )
    }
```

[Live Query Solution Page Link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FmusicArtist%20%3FmusicArtistSpouse%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fx%20dbo%3AmusicalArtist%20%3FmusicArtist.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FmusicArtist%20dbo%3Aspouse%20%3FmusicArtistSpouse.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%21%20EXISTS%20%7B%3FmusicArtistSpouse%20a%20dbo%3AMusicalArtist%7D%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)